# Send JavaScript to an iFrame that uses a different port?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have been having some issues sending JavaScript to an iFrame that uses a different port and after searching online it seems that the 'different port' part is causing the issue.

Here is the code sending JavaScript to the iFrame:

```
<script>
    var network = document.getElementById("1").contentWindow.kiwi.components.Network();

    $(".irc-channel-selector").click(function(event){
        network.join('#' + $(this).attr('data-irc-channel'));
    });
</script>
```

The iFrame does not use port 80 which appears to be the problem:

```
<iframe id="1" src="http://www.example.com:7888">
```

I understand that I can use something called postMessage to do the same as what I need but having read up on it online I'm not sure how it should be used, it seems pretty complex whereas I'm only used to basic JavaScript such as the code that I wrote above.

Can someone provide an example on how I can use this postMessage to mimic the behaviour above? Reading online documentation I do not understand how to use it in my scenario! :(

Comment: Do you have control over the javascript/html inside the iframe? If so, `postMessage` is probably your best solution, and trust me it isn't much more complicated than what you've already done! Check the examples in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage - I can post a possible answer if you do have control over the code inside the iframe.

Comment: @Sergio Yes I do control it, and if you could do that I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It's not very complicated to achieve this with `postMessage`. First, inside the iframe, you must expect a message:

```
var network = kiwi.components.Network();

function receive(event) {
    // it is important to check the origin. Here I'm assuming that the parent window has that origin (same address, default port).
    // if you don't check the origin any other site could include your iframe and send messages to it
    if (event.origin === "http://www.example.com") { 
        var message = event.data;
        // Assuming you might want different message types in the future. Otherwise message could be just the channel itself.
        if (message.type === "JOIN") { 
            network.join(message.channel);
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("message", receive, false);
```

Now your iframe page is expecting a message to make it join a channel. The parent page can send that message with:

```
$(".irc-channel-selector").click(function(event){
    var message = {
        type: "JOIN",
        channel: '#' + $(this).attr('data-irc-channel')
    };

    // Notice that again we're using the specific origin you used in your iframe
    document.getElementById("1").contentWindow.postMessage(message, "http://www.example.com:7888");
});
```

Here's a far more simple fiddle where a message is sent to the same window, since I'd have to host a page somewhere to have an iframe in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3h1Lw0j4/1/ -- Anyway it's useful to see how `event.origin` behaves.

Comment: Thanks, I've been playing with this for a couple of hours! I keep getting `Unable to post message to http://www.example.com:7778. Recipient has origin http://www.example.com.` in my console :(

Comment: Is there a redirect going on inside the iframe? try calling `postMessage` with  the origin specified in the error message: `contentWindow.postMessage(message, "http://www.example.com");`